# Use aws ca path certificates in mqtt

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, mqtt

I need to know how can we specify certificate which exists in aws certificate manager in node.js ssl options. I need to use that certificate in the implementation of mqtt.

For now I have created self signed certificates but that one are giving error

```
Error: self signed certificates
```

Once I pass the option rejectUnauthorized to false it works but with true it throws an error.

```
mqtt.connect('mqtts://domainname.com', {
                    clientId: clientId,
                    connectTimeout: config.connectTimeout,
                    rejectUnauthorized: false,
                    key: KEY,
                    cert: CERT,
                    ca: TRUSTED_CA
          });
```

I need to know is

1. is rejectUnauthorized the only way to remove the Error: self signed certificate?
2. how can we use the aws certificate manager certificate in the above options(as a common capath)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SSL certificates from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) with your own servers. You can only use the managed certificates with supported AWS managed services that are integrated with ACM. Supported services include Elastic Load Balancers, CloudFront and API Gateway.

AWS also has another service, AWS Certicate Manager Private Certificate Authority. You can create and manage your own certificates with this service. You pay a monthly fee (currently $400.00) and a per certificate fee ($0.75).

Comment: it means there are no default certificates in AWS that is used for public ssl certificate? The reason for this is I need to use mqtts and there will be many brokers so is rejectUnauthorized: false is ok to use then?

Comment: There is no such thing as a default SSL certificate. SSL Certificates are bound to `names` such as a domain name or machine name. You can have wildcard certificates such as `*.google.com` but not `*.com`. Look into Let's Encrypt. Their certifcates are free and the support wildcards such as `*.mydomain.com`.

Comment: I will look into letsencrypt. As there are many brokers who will be using our system will it be ok to use rejectUnauthorized: false for testing purpose?

Comment: I have one more question In my current machine I have created the certificates using openssl for testing on my machine, using mqttfx I can run it successfully but using node.js as mentioned in the above code i get Error: self signed certificate, and using mosquitto cmd I get TLS error occurred, can you please tell me the solution for these?

Comment: I would just get a valid supported SSL certificate and forgo trying to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

> is rejectUnauthorized the only way to remove the Error: self signed certificate?

If you want to remove the error you can either have your certificate signed by a trusted CA (you can do this going via Let's Encrypt).

Alternatively if you just need to remove the error for testing purposes then you can set the 'ca' parameter to match the self signed certificate. This is documented at https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options:

> The peer's certificate must be chainable to a CA trusted by the server for the connection to be authenticated. When using certificates that are not chainable to a well-known CA, the certificate's CA must be explicitly specified as a trusted or the connection will fail to authenticate. If the peer uses a certificate that doesn't match or chain to one of the default CAs, use the ca option to provide a CA certificate that the peer's certificate can match or chain to. **For self-signed certificates, the certificate is its own CA, and must be provided.**

Comment: Thank you for an answer, how we can provide common CA path or common CA path of AWS, can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: If you are using AWS IoT then you can use the Amazon AWS IoT CA by following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-create.html. Or you can provide your own by following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-your-own.html. If you are using another MQTT broker then you should consider using Let's Encrypt to have your certificate signed by a trusted CA.